# MathJax buttons/hotkeys script

Tags: discussion, math

I've written a script that lets you insert dollar symbols automatically(via a keyboard shortcut or button) in the editor window on Stack Exchange sites that support MathJax. You guys also get a special `NP` button(<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd>, S for sansserif) that encloses the selection in `$\mathsf{...}$`.

Also, note that <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd> lets you exit math mode--this lets you type math smoothly. For example, you can use <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd>, type PSPACE, and  then use <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd> to bring the cursor out of math mode, where you can continue typing. (It's been a big help to me on chem.SE, with the `\ce{...}` button--I can type chemical formulae within the flow of the code).

Also, you have <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>O</kbd> for Big O notation, but I doubt you'll use it.

Feel free to check it out!

[Installation instructions and details here](https://stackapps.com/questions/3373/mathjax-buttons)

Comment: Nice ! I'll try it out right now

Comment: @SureshVenkat: Great! Let me know about any bugs/etc (psst: I can't really program so bugs are expected) :P

Comment: Thanks for adding these features!

Answer (score 2):

Hmm. I don't see the buttons in the answer field, and the hotkeys don't appear to work. This is with FF 12.0 on Windows 7 64bit. Attached is a screenshot: [image]

Comment: That _is_ strange. I developed this in chrome, and it works fine, but I haven't checked back in FF yet. I'll do so...

Comment: It should work now, uninstall/reinstall. Some changes to GM since I last updated and FFs lack of `window.location.origin`. For some reason, my FF isn't showing the button bar itself (with the script disabled), so I can't test it :/

Comment: Let me know if it works/doesn't work. _Grumbles about firefox_ ;-)

Comment: Yup. works now ! thanks !